# Ubuntu loading problem

Tags: screen

I turned off my computer in the middle of the UBUNTU setup steps. And now it doean't boot at all. All i see is a white line appering and disapearing on a black screen

Comment: You have not posted a question.

Comment: That is a statement.

Comment: Reinstall and don't power it off this time.

Comment: We currently don't know what Ubuntu product, what release, nor what installer you are asking about. Ubuntu has various products, which have different ISO or installer options (for some products/releases) with *five* different installers you can select when you download an ISO.  You've not given us any details as to what product, release or ISO you elected to download & use, so we don't yet have any details we can offer yet.

Comment: If it was in the middle of partitioning (esp. *resizing down to make space*), I'd just go to your backups & restore data.. If it was in the middle of unsquashing data from your *unspecified* installation product/media; I'd expect the system to boot normally UNLESS you reduced partition sizes (*that will require boot loader to be installed for boot to work*).  If you were doing a *repair* type install & it was downloading the packages so they can be re-installed; I'd expect the system to boot. If new boot loader was being written, or you used an install that required it - you'll have to fix.

Comment: Its just black screen as it used to be even when i reinstalled

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to reinstall Ubuntu, and for that you need to be able to access the UEFI setup utility. It seems like Ubuntu is booting to a bootloader that points to nowhere and is unable to continue from there, so disconnect the cable to the hard drive that contains the bootloader. Insert the USB stick that you used to install Ubuntu, access the UEFI, and set the USB stick first in the boot sequence. Reconnect the cable to the hard drive. Then boot from the USB stick and reinstall Ubuntu.